# How to move files, images or docs into live site on as needed basis

Tags: media, feeds

For several reasons we can't upload files such as images, pdfs, xls, etc., to our production server.  It has to do with another application that is wrapped around Drupal7 and the revisioning process that application/framework has.

I need a method of moving the above file types into production that is outside the normal weekly migration process.  Currently, the content editor creates content in production, recreates it in staging and attaches the images or files as needed, then when the migration from staging to prod takes place the files are moved, we link.  So, as you can image this is not optimal.

What options are available out there - I am thinking to create a folder outside of deployment and have images and files sit there.  I have tried a feeds/xparser option, but see that it is tied to the content, so seems I would need to create a feed for each type and then for new content types as they are added.

What is a good method for moving image files or syncing image/file folder from staging to production?